# Is there any way to have boxed and by-move closures?

Tags: closures, rust

I need a closure that captures by-value and is called at most once, but I cannot have the function using the closure monomorphise on every passed closure, because the closures and functions are mutually recursive and the monomorphisation phase fails. I tried something like:

```
fn closure_user(closure: Box<FnOnce(usize) -> bool>) -> bool {
    closure(3)
}

fn main() {
    let big_data = vec![1, 2, 3, 4];
    closure_user(Box::new(|x| {
        let _ = big_data.into_iter();
        false
    }));
}
```

```
error[E0161]: cannot move a value of type dyn std::ops::FnOnce(usize) -> bool: the size of dyn std::ops::FnOnce(usize) -> bool cannot be statically determined
 --> src/main.rs:2:5
  |
2 |     closure(3)
  |     ^^^^^^^
```

The unboxed version is:

```
fn closure_user<F>(closure: F) -> bool
where
    F: FnOnce(usize) -> bool,
{
    closure(42)
}

fn main() {
    let big_data = vec![1, 2, 3, 4];
    closure_user(|x| {
        let _ = big_data.into_iter();
        false
    });
}
```

It seems that it is impossible to box and unbox the closure as a `FnOnce` trait object. Is there any way to have boxed (no type parameter) and by-move (one call only) closures?

Comment: See related question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30411594/moving-a-boxed-function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible, but for now you have to do it through the unstable [`std::thunk::Thunk`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/1.0.0/std/thunk/type.Thunk.html):

```
use std::thunk::{Invoke, Thunk};

fn closure_user(closure: Thunk<usize, bool>) -> bool {
    closure.invoke(3)
}

fn main() {
    let big_data = vec![1, 2, 3, 4];
    closure_user(Thunk::with_arg(|x| {
        let _ = big_data.into_iter();
        false
    }));
}
```

This is due to limitations on the current type system - it's not possible to move out from a trait object - and should be addressed soon. For more information, see the blog post [Purging Proc](http://smallcultfollowing.com/babysteps/blog/2014/11/26/purging-proc/).

Comment: Note that that answer is probably about legacy Rust. In current Rust it may fail to work.

Answer (score 3):

As of Rust 1.35, this is now possible using your original syntax:

```
fn closure_user(closure: Box<dyn FnOnce(usize) -> bool>) -> bool {
    closure(3)
}

fn main() {
    let big_data = vec![1, 2, 3, 4];
    closure_user(Box::new(|x| {
        let _ = big_data.into_iter();
        false
    }));
}
```