# "cannot move a value of type FnOnce" when moving a boxed function

Tags: rust

I'm trying to do some higher order programming in Rust, but I'm having some difficulty dealing with closures. Here's a code snippet that illustrates one of the problems I'm having:

```
pub enum Foo {
    Bar(Box<FnOnce(i32)>),
}

pub fn app(i: i32, arg: Foo) {
    match arg {
        Foo::Bar(f) => f(i),
    }
}
```

When I compile this piece of code I get the following error message:

```
error[E0161]: cannot move a value of type std::ops::FnOnce(i32) + 'static: the size of std::ops::FnOnce(i32) + 'static cannot be statically determined
 --> src/main.rs:7:24
  |
7 |         Foo::Bar(f) => f(i),
  |                        ^
```

Since I put the function in a `Box`, I would have thought that that would deal with the problem of the compiler not knowing the size. How can I make the above program compile?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Here's the `FnOnce` trait's definition (simplified a little):

```
pub trait FnOnce<Args> {
    type Output;

    fn call_once(self, args: Args) -> Self::Output;
}
```

To call a `FnOnce` closure, you need to be able to move the closure value itself into the invocation.  Note that `self` has to be the *actual* closure type; a `Box<dyn FnOnce>` is a different type altogether.

## [Rust 1.35](https://blog.rust-lang.org/2019/05/23/Rust-1.35.0.html#fn-closure-traits-implemented-for-boxdyn-fn)

`Box<dyn FnOnce>` is now able to be called; your original code works as-is.

## Prior versions

There *is* a type in the standard library for working around this situation: [`FnBox`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/boxed/trait.FnBox.html). *Unfortunately*, it's unstable.

Your alternate choices are:

- Refactor the code so that instead of `Box<FnOnce>`, you preserve the *actual* closure type.
- Use `Box<FnMut>` instead.
- Wait for `FnBox` to stabilise.
- Switch to a nightly compiler.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.Using the actual closure type is not an option for me since I need to be able to store different closures in the enum. I don't know how to make the `Box<FnMut>` suggestion work, I get an error when I try that. What I've managed to do instead is to just say `Box<fn(i32)>`. That helped me compile the example above. However, I cannot create an enum using that type since it doesn't match the type of the closure. So I guess I'm left with trying a nightly compiler.

Comment: @svenningsson: Use `Box<FnMut(i32)>` instead; because `FnMut` is "object safe", you *can* call one through a `Box` (or any indirection, really).  The only thing you can't do is have the closure consume values (though you can work around that with `Option`).

Comment: The error I get when I try `Box<FnMut(i32)>` is the following:
cannot borrow immutable `Box` content `*f` as mutable
src/lib.rs:36     Foo::Bar(f) => f(i)

Comment: @svenningsson: A `FnMut` needs to be able to mutate the closure value when called, so use `Foo::Bar(mut f) => f(i)` instead to make the `f` binding mutable.

Comment: Ok thanks. That makes my example compile. Unfortunately, using `FnMut` prevents me from creating the kind of closures I like, but that's a different problem and maybe I can find a way around that.

Comment: Just want to confirm that `FnBox` solves my problem. Thanks again!

Comment: There's another choice: Just copy the `FnBox` implementation. This is what crossbeam does, and it's pretty simple - just a few lines - since they only need a specific function, which might be ok for you too. See https://github.com/crossbeam-rs/crossbeam/blob/07245b3f3d2d938017581a71c02754be9e794ae8/src/lib.rs#L43

Answer (score 2):

It is unlikely [`FnBox`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/boxed/trait.FnBox.html) becomes stable, but for the time being you can wrap the `F: FnOnce(...) -> ...` in an `Option<F>`, bind it in a mutable closure and unwrap and call it inside (so it panics if it gets called more than once); the resulting closure can be boxed as `Box<FnMut(...) -> ...>`, which you might want to wrap somehow to make sure it only gets used ("called") once.

See (my) [`boxfnonce`](https://crates.io/crates/boxfnonce) crate.