# How can I write a function that takes a collection of closures?

Tags: rust

I am trying to write a function that takes a collection of closures of type `Fn() -> ()`, i.e. each closure takes no args, returns nothing (and I want them to be `FnOnce` actually, so as to move all its environment into the closure object).

I've tried many things (like using `Box<Fn() -> ()>` and using `&'static`) but I just can't get this working.

I created a gist in the [Rust Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=421151b3342c80078bf595aef0c8af56&version=stable) to show what I am trying to do, approximately.

Here's the simplified code:

```
fn run_all_tests<I>(tests: I)
where
    I: IntoIterator<Item = Box<FnOnce() -> ()>>,
{
}

fn main() {
    let examples = [1, 2, 3];

    run_all_tests(examples.iter().map(
        |ex| Box::new(move |ex| assert!(ex > 0)),
    ));
}
```

The error:

```
error[E0271]: type mismatch resolving `<[closure@src/main.rs:11:9: 11:49] as std::ops::FnOnce<(&{integer},)>>::Output == std::boxed::Box<std::ops::FnOnce() + 'static>`
  --> src/main.rs:10:5
   |
10 |     run_all_tests(examples.iter().map(
   |     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^ expected closure, found trait std::ops::FnOnce
   |
   = note: expected type `std::boxed::Box<[closure@src/main.rs:11:23: 11:48]>`
              found type `std::boxed::Box<std::ops::FnOnce() + 'static>`
   = note: required because of the requirements on the impl of `std::iter::Iterator` for `std::iter::Map<std::slice::Iter<'_, {integer}>, [closure@src/main.rs:11:9: 11:49]>`
   = note: required by `run_all_tests`
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several issues with the code:

1. Your boxed closure takes a parameter `ex`, but the trait `FnOnce()` takes no parameters. The parameter `ex` also shadows the parameter `ex` from the outer closure, so I assume you meant the inner closure to take no parameters: `move || assert!(ex > 0)`.
2. Type mismatch in `ex > 0` because of comparing reference to non-reference. Can be fixed by dereferencing the outer closure parameter during pattern matching: `|&ex| ....`
3. Type inference isn't strong enough to discover that the iterator returned by `map` should be over `Box<FnOnce()>` rather than `Box<unique closure object>`. You can add an explicit cast to fix this: `Box::new(move || assert!(ex > 0)) as Box<FnOnce()>`
4. At this point, the code will compile, but you will get a compilation error when you add a call to the boxed `FnOnce()` due to a language limitation. See ["cannot move a value of type FnOnce" when moving a boxed function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30411594/cannot-move-a-value-of-type-fnonce-when-moving-a-boxed-function). On nightly Rust, you can change `FnOnce` to `FnBox`. Otherwise, you can use `FnMut` instead or use one of the workarounds from that question. There's another workaround based on defining an extra trait given [in the Rust book](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/second-edition/ch20-05-sending-requests-via-channels.html) (see section between listing 20-20 and listing 20-21).

Here is the fixed code using `FnBox`:

```
#![feature(fnbox)]
use std::boxed::FnBox;

fn run_all_tests<I>(tests: I)
where
    I: IntoIterator<Item = Box<FnBox()>>,
{
    for t in tests {
        t();
    }
}

fn main() {
    let examples = [1, 2, 3];

    run_all_tests(examples.iter().map(|&ex| {
        Box::new(move || assert!(ex > 0)) as Box<FnBox()>
    }));
}
```