# Why is calling a FnOnce closure a move?

Tags: rust, closures, move-semantics

I'm trying to pass in a closure to a function that will then mutate something passed into it within the scope of the function.  Based on my current understanding of Rust, that should look something like this:

```
pub fn call_something(callback: &FnOnce(&mut Vec<i32>)) {
    let mut my_vec = vec![0, 1, 2, 3, 4];
    callback(&mut my_vec);
}
```

That results in these errors:

```
error[E0161]: cannot move a value of type dyn for<'r> std::ops::FnOnce(&'r mut std::vec::Vec<i32>): the size of dyn for<'r> std::ops::FnOnce(&'r mut std::vec::Vec<i32>) cannot be statically determined
 --> src/lib.rs:3:5
  |
3 |     callback(&mut my_vec);
  |     ^^^^^^^^

error[E0507]: cannot move out of borrowed content
 --> src/lib.rs:3:5
  |
3 |     callback(&mut my_vec);
  |     ^^^^^^^^ cannot move out of borrowed content
```

Why is calling a `FnOnce` a move?  What am I missing here?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> Why is calling a `FnOnce` a move?

Because that's [the *definition* of what makes a closure `FnOnce`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ops/trait.FnOnce.html):

```
extern "rust-call" fn call_once(self, args: Args) -> Self::Output
//                              ^^^^
```

Contrast this to [`FnMut`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ops/trait.FnMut.html) and [`Fn`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ops/trait.Fn.html):

```
extern "rust-call" fn call_mut(&mut self, args: Args) -> Self::Output
//                             ^^^^^^^^^
```

```
extern "rust-call" fn call(&self, args: Args) -> Self::Output
//                         ^^^^^
```

See also:

- [When does a closure implement Fn, FnMut and FnOnce?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30177395/155423)
- ["cannot move a value of type FnOnce" when moving a boxed function](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30411594/155423)
- [Cannot move out of borrowed content](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28158738/155423)

---

You probably want

```
pub fn call_something(callback: impl FnOnce(&mut Vec<i32>))
```

or

```
pub fn call_something<F>(callback: F)
where
    F: FnOnce(&mut Vec<i32>),
```

These are identical. They both take ownership of the closure, which means that you can call the closure and consume it in the process.