# Why does the multithreaded web server example from the Rust book not compile?

Tags: rust

This is a [code sample from the book](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/2018-edition/ch20-02-multithreaded.html):

```
use std::{
    sync::{mpsc, Arc, Mutex},
    thread,
};

struct Worker {
    id: usize,
    thread: thread::JoinHandle<()>,
}

impl Worker {
    fn new(
        id: usize,
        receiver: Arc<Mutex<mpsc::Receiver<Box<dyn FnOnce() + Send + 'static>>>>,
    ) -> Worker {
        let thread = thread::spawn(move || loop {
            let job = receiver.lock().unwrap().recv().unwrap();

            println!("Worker {} got a job; executing.", id);

            (*job)();
        });

        Worker { id, thread }
    }
}
```

[playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2015&gist=e3f0ed7a145426b37829374481355807)

It doesn't compile:

```
error[E0161]: cannot move a value of type dyn std::ops::FnOnce() + std::marker::Send: the size of dyn std::ops::FnOnce() + std::marker::Send cannot be statically determined
  --> src/lib.rs:21:13
   |
21 |             (*job)();
   |             ^^^^^^
```

Is this a bug in the book or am I missing something?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems that you are referring to the section of the book that is immediately followed by the text:

> Theoretically, this code should compile. Unfortunately, the Rust
>   compiler isn’t perfect yet, and we get this error:
>
> ```
> error[E0161]: cannot move a value of type std::ops::FnOnce() +
> std::marker::Send: the size of std::ops::FnOnce() + std::marker::Send cannot be
> statically determined
>   --> src/lib.rs:63:17
>    |
> 63 |                 (*job)();
>    |                 ^^^^^^
> ```

Thus no, it's **not** a bug in the book; they deliberately included that to show a problem. Please continue reading the chapter to see how they suggest addressing it.

See also:

- ["cannot move a value of type FnOnce" when moving a boxed function](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30411594/155423)

Comment: I start to hate their way of teaching things . They could at least tell before hand that this isnt a working example

Comment: @nikoss If you are aren't happy with the current situation (which I can understand) you're always welcome to open an issue/pull request [at github](https://github.com/rust-lang/book) and improve the situation. This is an important step, because somebody who already knows rust, does not stumple upon these errors, because they know what's up. But newcommers like you are having a hard time, and I think this should be improved. Feel free to be part of the rust community <3