# How to pass a closure via dynamic dispatch in an object-safe method?

Tags: rust, closures, traits, trait-objects

How do you pass a closure to an object-safe trait method or otherwise via dynamic dispatch?

I have [answered this myself](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59275774/155423), but the answer leaves something wanting: `FnOnce` closures must be boxed since they are not sized and must be consumed on use (thus cannot be passed by reference).

Comment: "`FnOnce` closures must be boxed" this [has been possible since 1.35.0 (2019-05-23)](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/blob/master/RELEASES.md#language-4)

Comment: See also [“cannot move a value of type FnOnce” when moving a boxed function](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30411594/155423)

Comment: It's rather unclear what you are asking. The code you have provided [compiles fine](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=f3fd06fc369f80e835e1db4898591432) — what exactly are you attempting to demonstrate with it? Are you asking if there's some way of passing a `FnOnce` closure via dynamic dispatch without using a `Box` (and presumably not with another kind of heap-allocation)?

Answer (score 2):

You can pass it without using `Box`:

```
fn pass_fn_once(do_thing: &dyn FnOnce()) {
    //do_thing();
}

fn main() {
    pass_fn_once(&|| println!("Hello!"));
}
```

However, you won't be able to actually call `do_thing` in `pass_fn_once`, since it is only borrowed - [calling an `FnOnce` consumes it](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ops/trait.FnOnce.html).

If they are `Box`ed, you can be sure that `pass_fn_once` took ownership so that the closure can be thrown away afterwards.

Answer (score 2):

`Fn` and `FnMut` closures can be passed by reference, as follows. `FnOnce` can be *passed* by reference but not *called* unless it is *owned*, e.g. by a `Box`.

```rust
fn pass_fn(get_num: &dyn Fn() -> i32) {
    let _num = get_num();
}

fn pass_fn_mut(set_num: &mut dyn FnMut(i32)) {
    set_num(6);
}

fn pass_fn_once(do_thing: Box<dyn FnOnce()>) {
    do_thing();
}

fn main() {
    pass_fn(&|| 2);

    let mut x = 1;
    pass_fn_mut(&mut |y| x = y);

    pass_fn_once(Box::new(|| println!("Hello!")));
}
```

Comment: Hasn't `impl Trait` allowed us to drop the `Box`?