# Is this the right way to capture a string by value?

Tags: rust, closures

I'm making a functional builder that configures an object such as:

```
struct Person
{
  name: String,
  position: String
}
```

The builder itself keeps a list of boxed closures to be applied to the object when it needs to be constructed:

```
struct FunctionalBuilder<TSubject>
  where TSubject : Default
{
  actions: Vec<Box<dyn Fn(&mut TSubject) -> ()>>
}

impl<TSubject> FunctionalBuilder<TSubject>
  where TSubject : Default
{
  fn build(self) -> TSubject
  {
    let mut subj = TSubject::default();
    for action in self.actions
    {
      (*action)(&mut subj);
    }
    subj
  }
}
```

The idea being that one can aggregate this builder and then customize it for an object such as `Person`. Now, let's say I want to have a builder method `called()` that takes a name and saves the assignment of the name in the closure. I implement it as follows:

```
impl PersonBuilder
{
  pub fn called(mut self, name: &str) -> PersonBuilder
  {
    let value = name.to_string();
    self.builder.actions.push(Box::new(move |x| {
      x.name = value.clone();
    }));
    self
  }
}
```

Is this the right way of doing things? Is there a better way that avoids the temporary variable and `clone()` call?

Complete working example:

```rust
#[derive(Debug, Default)]
struct Person {
    name: String,
    position: String,
}

struct FunctionalBuilder<TSubject>
where
    TSubject: Default,
{
    actions: Vec<Box<dyn Fn(&mut TSubject) -> ()>>,
}

impl<TSubject> FunctionalBuilder<TSubject>
where
    TSubject: Default,
{
    fn build(self) -> TSubject {
        let mut subj = TSubject::default();
        for action in self.actions {
            (*action)(&mut subj);
        }
        subj
    }

    fn new() -> FunctionalBuilder<TSubject> {
        Self {
            actions: Vec::new(),
        }
    }
}

struct PersonBuilder {
    builder: FunctionalBuilder<Person>,
}

impl PersonBuilder {
    pub fn new() -> Self {
        PersonBuilder {
            builder: FunctionalBuilder::<Person>::new(),
        }
    }

    pub fn called(mut self, name: &str) -> PersonBuilder {
        let value = name.to_string();
        self.builder.actions.push(Box::new(move |x| {
            x.name = value;
        }));
        self
    }

    pub fn build(self) -> Person {
        self.builder.build()
    }
}

pub fn main() {
    let builder = PersonBuilder::new();
    let me = builder.called("Dmitri").build();
    println!("{:?}", me);
}
```

https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=27eb6283836a478d5c68aa025aa4698d

Comment: @Stargateur added link to complete working example

Comment: That said I don't think this kind of code is very rusty.

Comment: Also, you could just require static lifetime https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=cfbba476a60504c60f97f89616f1ec54

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You already do it, `value` is owned by your closure, the problem is that you require the `Fn` trait. This mean that `action` (the function) need to be able to be called many times. This mean `value` need to be cloned to keep it valid inside the closure. The closure can't give away its ownership.

One way would be to use `FnOnce`, which would make it possible to remove the `clone`, but this means that the builder can only be used once. To do this, use `actions: Vec<Box<dyn FnOnce(&mut TSubject) -> ()>>,` and `action(&mut subj);`.

More:

- ["cannot move a value of type FnOnce" when moving a boxed function](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30411594/7076153)
- [`Fn*` closure traits implemented for `Box<dyn Fn*>`](https://blog.rust-lang.org/2019/05/23/Rust-1.35.0.html#fn-closure-traits-implemented-for-boxdyn-fn)

Comment: While your suggestion works, I don't understand *why* it works. `action` is a `Box<dyn FnOnce>`, how does it become legal to just call `action(&mut subj)` instead of through `*action`?

Comment: @DmitriNesteruk your original doesn't need *action either https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=ffbababfeb9b683b6b9b7cfd2ef4e9d0 that just I need to get rid of it because Box<FnOnce> need to be consume not just the FnOnce inside. That why I add the link in More, I added the blog announcement too. This is quite a advance topic you are dealing here. https://doc.rust-lang.org/1.34.0/std/boxed/trait.FnBox.html#tymethod.call_box You can see this function need to consume the box